# Commercial/free third-party application to browse/watch YouTube, is that legal?

Tags: copyright, internet, terms-of-service

Let's say there is an internet browser that allows browsing/watching content from YouTube while blocking their ads. Also the browser can be a free or paid application, or can show ads from a third-party, and it's distributed through digital stores like the Apple's AppStore or Google Play. It doesn't allow downloading, sharing, or storing of videos nor any content, but only allows watching the content while the application is online.

**Would this application be legal?**

Comment: YouTube's TOS prohibits it under 5.1E: *you agree not to use the Service (including the YouTube Player) for any of the following commercial uses unless you obtain YouTube's prior written approval:
the sale of advertising, sponsorships or promotions placed on or within the Service, or Content; the sale of advertising, sponsorships or promotions on any page of an ad-enabled blog or website containing Content delivered via the Service unless other material not obtained from YouTube appears on the same page and is of sufficient value to be the basis for such sales*.